# JSON result format

Tags: php, json, sql-server

```
<?php
include 'Connection.php';

if(isset($_REQUEST["insert"])) 
{ 
$user = $_GET['user'];
$pwd = $_GET['pass'];

$sql = "select RegNo,UserName,password from Std_Reg where Username= '$user' and Password = '$pwd'";
//$sql = "select * from Std_Reg";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);



$result = array(); 

do {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
       $result[] = $row; 
    }
} while (sqlsrv_next_result($stmt));

if(count($result)>0)
{
    $result1['status']=1;//"Login successfully";
    array_push($result,$result1);
}
else
{

    $result1['status']=0;//"Record not found";
    array_push($result,$result1);
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn); //Close the connnectiokn first

echo json_encode($result); //You will get the encoded array variable
}
?>
```

This gives me:

```
[{"RegNo":"xyz","UserName":"abc","password":"123"},{"status":1}].
```

I need:

```
[{"status":1},{"RegNo":"xyz","UserName":"abc","password":"123"}].
```

how can I get the above result? What should I change in the PHP file?

Comment: where you need to have this values, in PHP or in JS

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: You also are open to SQL injections, which paired with plain text passwords is a big problem.

Comment: Both JSON strings mean the same the order doesn't matter.. so you dont have to fix it.

Comment: a better JSON structure would be `{ "status": 1, "data": [{"RegNo":"xyz","UserName":"abc","password":"123"}] }`. Right now it looks to the person viewing the JSON as if the "status" object is a row from the DB, when it isn't. It'd be hard to differentiate them and also irritating when looping through or binding the results if one item always had to be ignored. So I think you would be better to re-structure it so it's clear the "status" is a separate piece of information from the actual payload of data.

Answer (score 1):

Much is wrong here. Starting from the top:

- You are including the user's password in the URL, leaving it in their browser history and many other places
- You are inserting user-supplied data into a database query without sanitizing it, you are wide open for SQL injection attacks
- You are storing plaintext passwords in the database, which makes it easy for an attacker to get them with the aforementioned injection attack
- You are looping through multiple result sets though you only have one
- If you're pulling a single user record you don't really need to put in a `while` loop at all
- You are sending your JSON with an incorrect MIME type
- JSON is a data transfer format, it shouldn't matter what order the elements are in. If it does matter, somebody has done something wrong.

Try something like this instead:

```
<?php
include 'Connection.php';

if(isset($_REQUEST["insert"])) {
    // we are using POST and not GET
    $user   = $_POST["user"];
    $pwd    = $_POST["pass"];
//    uncomment this once your passwords are stored securely
//    $pwd    = password_hash($_POST["pass"], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $sql    = "SELECT RegNo, UserName, password FROM Std_Reg WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?";
    $params = array($user, $pwd);
    // see how the parameters are passed separately and replace the ? in the query
    $stmt   = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
    // we can check for rows before looping through the result set
    if (sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt)) {
        // this is how to append to an array, array_push() is not PHP-like
        $result[] = array("status" => 1);
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $result[] = $row; 
        }
    } else {
        // note also the [] construct automatically creates the variable
        $result[] = array("status"=>0);
    }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
    sqlsrv_close($conn);
    // this isn't just plain text
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($result);
}
?>
```